# AWSCloudFormation - cfn-init failed to run command

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation for installing elasticsearch.
I am downloading and extracting tar.gz.
The following is my EC2 instance section :

```
 "masterinstance": {
        "Type": "AWS: : EC2: : Instance",
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS: : CloudFormation: : Init": {

                  "configSets" : {
                    "ascending" : [ "config1" , "config2" ]

                    },
                "config1": {
                    "sources": {
                        "/home/ubuntu/": "https: //s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxx/elasticsearch.tar.gz"
                    },
                    "files": {
                        "/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml": {
                            "content": {
                                "Fn: : Join": [
                                    "",
                                    [
                                        xxxxxxxx
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }

                },

                    "config2" : {
                        "commands": {
                        "runservice": {
                         "command": "~/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch",
                         "cwd" : "~",
                         "test" : "~/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch > test.txt",
                         "ignoreErrors" : "false"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-xxxxxxxxxx",
            "InstanceType": {
                "Ref": "InstanceTypeParameter"
            },
            "Tags": [
                xxxxxxxx
            ],
            "KeyName": "everybody",
            "NetworkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "GroupSet": [
                        {
                            "Ref": "newSecurity"
                        }
                    ],
                    "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
                    "DeviceIndex": "0",
                    "SubnetId": {
                        "Ref": "oneSubnet"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "UserData": {
                "Fn: : Base64": {
                    "Fn: : Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "#!/bin/bash\n",

                            "sudo add-apt-repository-yppa: webupd8team/java\n",
                            "sudo apt-get update\n",
                            "echo'oracle-java8-installershared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1selecttrue'|sudo debconf-set-selections\n",
                            "sudo apt-getinstall-yoracle-java8-installer\n",

                            "apt-get update\n",
                            "apt-get-y installpython-setuptools\n",
                            "easy_installhttps: //s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
                            "/usr/local/bin/cfn-init",
                            "--stack Elasticsearch",
                            "--resource masterinstance",
                            "--configsets ascending",
                            "-v\n"

                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
```

}
    }

I am using `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` for configuration and other settings.
After extracting the tar , I want to start elasticsearch , which I am doing through the `command` section in `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` but ,
after the complete creation of stack when I ssh into my instances, I am not able to see my elasticsearch service running.
All other things like extracting tar and creating file is working correctly.

I have gone through the cfn-init.log , it gives me the following information :

```
2016-07-19 05:53:15,776 P2745 [INFO] Test for Command runservice
2016-07-19 05:53:15,778 P2745 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2016-07-19 05:53:15,778 P2745 [INFO]    /bin/sh: 1: ~/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch: not found
2016-07-19 05:53:15,778 P2745 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-19 05:53:15,779 P2745 [ERROR] Exited with error code 127
~
```

If I fire the above command `~/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch` directly on my instance then it is working perfectly.

What I am doing wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: is there any information in the logs?

Comment: If an answer below solved your question, don't forget to [mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/327137).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the home directory (~) is evaluating to a different user (not Ubuntu) when trying to run ES. I think CFN-Init runs as the root user instead of as ubuntu/ec2-user. Try to change the paths in the config2 command block to fully qualified paths (/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch).

Comment: I have also tried that , but then the ES is started as root and then I face the `runtime error : don't run elasticsearch as root.`

Is root is the user who runs all the script and commands at boottime and at the time of running user data and cfn-init metadata ?

Comment: Yeah, all commands will be run as root by default. You could do a couple things:

Run the elasticsearch command as a specific user: 
`sudo -H -u username /home/ubuntu/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`.

Or, wrap the elasticsearch start command in an upstart/sysv script and then set the UID to launch it as a specific user. I would suggest doing this  to make it easier to keep it running, restart, etc, but it is a bit more of a time investment.

Comment: Thank you very much for this knowledge, what I did is made changes in elasticsearch and allowed service to be run as root.

Now it is working.
Thanks.